# Javascript inheriting instance attributes?

Tags: javascript

```
function A(){
  // sort of like this
  // this.arr = [];
}

function B(){
  // not here though
  // this.arr = [];
}

B.prototype = new A(); // all B instances would share this prototypes attributes

// I want all B instances to have an arr attributes (array)
// of their own but I want the parent class to define it

var b1 = new B();
var b2 = new B();

b1.arr.push(1);
b2.arr.push(2);

b1.arr.length === 1; // should be true
b2.arr.length === 1; // should be true
```

I want write code in `A` that would define a `arr` variable for each instance of a child class `B` such that `arr` is a new object for each `B` instance.  I could make this happen by setting `this.arr = []` in the `B` constructor, but is this possible to accomplish with code written onto `A` instead?

Answer (score 2):

There is a big problem in your idea of inheritance in Javascript. In javascript, you really have objects and that's pretty much it. A constructor is a method that is called with `new` and create a new object.

This part of code isn't really `right` as you're creating a prototype using the object created from A... That said, you're not really using the prototype `A`. As inheritance per say doesn't really exist, you'll have to implement something that will call every constructors that are required to create object `B`.

```
B.prototype = new A();
```

You should use this method instead:

```
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype)
```

In this case, you'll have all the prototypes of A in B... But you'll still have to call the constructor of `A` if it is necessary.

```
function A() {
   this.arr = []
}

function B() {
    A.call(this)
}
```

Using more complex library, you could end up with inheritance and something similar to `super` in python. If you're really into that, you could also create a structure that will automatically call each constructor of each sub prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
```

With [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) you can create an object with a specific prototype, and I believe this is what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of that to work is:

```
function A(){
   this.arr = [];
}

function B(){
   A.call(this); 
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to call `new A()`. As you're calling the constructor of A in the constructor of B, it will be as if you called the constructor twice. In the prototype of B you really only need to copy the prototype of `A` with `Object.create`.